# Comp Mgmt vs PowerShell

Tags: powershell, remote-access, administrator

So I'm writing a script to check if a SID is a local user/group on a remote machine. But I want to do so without having Admin access to the remote machine.

I'm able to use Computer Management to look at the Remote computer's Users and Groups without Administrator access.

ManagementObjectSearcher, Get-CimInstance, Get-WMIObject all require administrator access on our domain and give me an access denied.

I can't use net user | localgroup remotely without PSExec, which may still require admin access.

What does Computer Management use to connect to its remote machines? I can't seem to find an answer on google.

Or

How can I accomplish verifying if a SID is local on a remote machine without administrator access to that machine? (via PowerShell)

Comment: I would say it is very lame not to have admin access and trying to accomplish it. Ideally these operations are hardcore admin works. So, in a given scenario to achieve this, you need to have the admin access.

Comment: Where does the "no admin" requirement arise from, anyway? You might have some luck with Sysinternals' `psgetsid`.

Comment: The company I'm currently working with are cracking down on who has access to what and it may be an issue with what I'm creating. I just feel there has to be a way since I still have access to the remote machine's local users/groups through Comp Mgmt w/o admin access. This works great! It proves there's a way to get it without Admin access. Now I wanna know how PSGetSID is doing it.

Comment: In CMD are you able to run `wmic /node:computername useraccount get name,sid`? I would suspect it is the same as Get-WMIObject.

Comment: Yeah, I received access denied.

Comment: Not sure if this would work without admin permissions, but try: `$sid = "S-1-5-21-XXXXXXXXX-XXXXXXXXXX-XXXXXXXXX-XXX"; try { (New-Object System.Security.Principal.SecurityIdentifier($sid)).Translate([System.Security.Principal.NTAccount]).Value }  catch { Write-Warning "Could not find user with SID $sid" }`

Answer (score 0):

While working on another project I found the answer to this... ADSI or System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry. I would say it's a good guess that Computer Management uses this to do it and PSGetSID might as well. Here is the code I code used in case anyone wanted to see it.

```
$Computer = 'Computer1'
$SID = 'S-1-5-21-1785707171-2823430725-1593205055-500'

[ADSI]$ADSI = "WinNT://$Computer"

$ADSI.Children | 
    Select-Object -Property `
        @{Name='Name'; Expression={$_.Name.Value}},
        @{Name='SID'; Expression={
                (New-Object System.Security.Principal.SecurityIdentifier($_.objectsid.value,0)).Value
            }
         } |
    Where-object -FilterScript { $_.SID -eq $SID }
```